# Print to a label printer from a web site / web application?

Tags: browser, printing, cross-browser, label

Are there any known label printers that will accept print commands from a web site or web application?

Specifically, the one-off label printers such as Dymo, Brother, Zebra, etc.

Has anyone had success in printing to these printers (without using an Internet Explorer-Only hack or ActiveX control)

I would think that, eventually, there would have to be a solution as we move into a more browser-centric world.

Answer (score 34):

Wow. I know this was asked over 4 years ago, but having burnt the better part of a week in search of a robust method of printing labels from a web app, I had to voice in here.

Here's what I've found:

- DYMO seems the most likely candidate for excellence. But no, turns out it only prints from (a) its own app, or (b) something using its SDK. The DYMO SDK uses an XML drawing model that is both overly complex and limited in layout and styling. The documentation is scattered and incomprehensible (e.g. what are the `<Bounds>` values for the common label sizes? There's no description of the tag parameters anywhere!) So frustrating, so disappointing.
- There's [**qz** (was jzebra)](http://qzindustries.com/), which enables browser printing for devices that speak EPL, ZPL, FGL, ESC/POS, EPCL and CPCL ... which includes the Zebra series. It requires a load of integration (running a web server on device the label printer is attached to), but it works.
- There's a well designed [3rd party app by **Peninsula**](http://www.peninsula-group.com/mac-thermal-printer-driver/), which works for DYMO (among others), but requires a middle-step of printing from browser to PDF. They also assume you'll never scale what you want printed down less than 70%, which is incorrect.

The OP says "I would think that, eventually, there would have to be a solution as we move into a more browser-centric world." Four years later, I'd go a step further and suggest any label printer that can't print off a browser (or just behave like a regular printer with small paper) is falling WAY short of its potential. Layout in HTML+CSS is a snap. Browsers parse it perfectly, and render it at any resolution to any output device. It seems so obvious.

If anyone knows of a thermal label printer that prints from the browser instead of imprisoning you in archaic integration methodologies, I'd very much like to know!

Comment: We have a Dymo LabelWriter 450 Twin Turbo that we can print to from a browser. We're having issues controlling the margin when printing html, but it does print.

Comment: @TimGautier - can you get this printing from a browser silently? i.e. without the print dialog appearing?

Comment: Nope. I think you'd need some sort of browser plugin to do something like that. Anything else will go through the browser's print dialog.

Comment: Dymo printers can print from javascript without a print dialog.

Comment: @MarkCooper You can do this with chrome's kiosk printing mode. I've had success printing from page to zebra printer without requiring the user to do anything.

Comment: @JayShepherd but that only works in Chrome I guess? - so limited use-case :-(

Comment: What's the status 1.5 years later? Found this for Zebra but it require a networkable device. https://developer.zebra.com/community/technologies/printers/label-printers/blog/2015/03/31/printing-from-websites-part-2

Comment: About the Dymo XML drawing model – we're putting a single PNG image (generated from a PDF) inside the XML, so we're not limited by their XML layout.

Comment: I'm retracing your steps and I find it quite amazing how backwards the entire printer world seems to be. Enabling printing directly from browsers seems like such an obvious competitive advantage, and yet universal solutions are still few. I downloaded an SDK from Dymo for Mac, but I think it is a joke, after going through numerous VISE Installer screens I ended up with a bunch of applescript files.

So far the best option seems to be the Zebra Browser Print SDK.

Answer (score 9):

The Dymo printers have a browser plugin that let you print from [javascript](http://developers.dymo.com/2010/06/02/dymo-label-framework-javascript-library-samples-print-a-label/). Very easy to use.

Revisiting this question a few years later.

The networked Zebra printers are easy to print to. In one project I had the webapplication open a socket to the printer and feed it instructions in ZPL.

Comment: Thanks for adding a link to this I would have had a hard time finding this without knowing it existed.

Answer (score 6):

You could also trying looking [PrintNode](http://www.printnode.com) which provide a cloud printing solution and means you can print straight to any printer over the internet.

Answer (score 4):

A cross-browser/platform-compatible web page/web page script doesn't have the low-level access necessary to transmit printer language command (such as Zebra Printer Language [ZPL]) to the printer. In order to do this, an ActiveX control/browser plugin/applet/similar bit of executable code is required. This limitation is non-printer specific, coming from the browser not the printer manufacturer.

However, many label printers allow you to print to them as though they were normal printers--just ones that print to very small pieces of paper. You could layout your label using HTML/CSS. When displaying the results, instruct the user to go to "File > Print" and select their label printer before clicking print.

Hope this helps,
Ben

Comment: +1 Good idea. Though it's probably better to send the labels as PDF, that way you have better control over output formatting than using HTML.

Comment: "many label printers allow you to print to them as though they were normal printers". Are there any printers that dosen't allow us to print to them just like normal printers!??

Answer (score 3):

Zebra now has a tool called 'BrowserPrint' that works like PrintNode specifically for Zebra printers. (unlike Printnode, it's free to use with Zebra printers)

Some printers also have ppd files available and/or can be configured in cups on a linux platform system or otherwise connected and spoken too via linux. (which then means it's not impossible to use something from shell scripting, php, perl or other methods to print to it by building a simple server daemon or setting up something like apache or lighttpd on a linux box or even a raspberry pi connected to the printer)

Comment: Here's the link: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/browser-print.html

Answer (score 0):

You can print from a signed Java applet, or from a [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) application:

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/printing/

That should work, if you format your print output so it fits on the labels.

Note that most modern browsers are restricting support for Java applets, so you may run into trouble with an applet, depending on the browsers in use. In particular, Google Chrome will [stop supporting Java applets in September 2015](http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation). These restrictions do *not* apply to Java Web Start, which should continue to work.

Comment: This option is soon going to be unusable as various browser manufacturers restrict and then remove the ability for Java applets to run https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1247383?hl=en

Answer (score -6):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Reflection;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GetAllPrinterList();
        this.textBox1.Attributes.Add(
    "onkeypress", "button_click(this,'" + this.Button1.ClientID + "')");
        this.lstPrinterList.Attributes.Add(
    "onkeypress", "button_click(this,'" + this.Button1.ClientID + "')");

    }

    private void GetAllPrinterList()
    {
        //ManagementScope objScope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath); //For the local Access
        //objScope.Connect();

        //SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery();
        //selectQuery.QueryString = "Select * from win32_Printer";
        //ManagementObjectSearcher MOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objScope, selectQuery);
        //ManagementObjectCollection MOC = MOS.Get();
        //foreach (ManagementObject mo in MOC)
        //{
        //    lstPrinterList.Items.Add(mo["Name"].ToString());
        //    //lstPrinterList.Items.Add(new ListItem(mo["Name"].ToString()));

        //}

        lstPrinterList.Items.Add("\\\\10.32.65.6\\Parcel-Zebra-FDX ZM400");
        lstPrinterList.Items.Add("\\\\10.32.65.4\\Singles_Station_Z_Printer");
        lstPrinterList.Items.Add("\\\\10.32.65.12\\ZebraZ4M-Packaging");
        if (lstPrinterList.Items.Count > 3)
        {
        lstPrinterList.Items.RemoveAt(5);
        lstPrinterList.Items.RemoveAt(4);
        lstPrinterList.Items.RemoveAt(3);

        }

        //LocalPrintServer printServer = new LocalPrintServer();
        //string printer;
        //printer = LocalPrintServer.DefaultPrintQueue;
        //System.Management.ObjectQuery oquery =
        //        new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

        //    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mosearcher =
        //        new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(oquery);

        //    System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mosearcher.Get();

        //    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        //    {
        //        System.Management.PropertyDataCollection pdc = mo.Properties;
        //        foreach (System.Management.PropertyData pd in pdc)
        //        {
        //           // if ((bool)mo["Network"])
        //           // {
        //                lstPrinterList.Items.Add(mo["Name"].ToString());
        //           // }
        //        }
        //    }

        //}
        //        using (var printServer = new PrintServer(string.Format(@"\\{0}", PrinterServerName)))
        //{
        //    foreach (var queue in printServer.GetPrintQueues())
        //    {
        //        if (!queue.IsShared)
        //        {
        //            continue;
        //        }
        //        Debug.WriteLine(queue.Name);
        //     }
        // }
        //foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
        //{
        //MessageBox.Show(printer);
        //System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox lstPrinterList = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox();
        //System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox lstPrinterList = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox)Page.FindControl("lstPrinterList");
        //lstPrinterList.Text = "Zebra 110PAX4 (203 ;dpi)";

        //lstPrinterList.Items.Add(printer.ToString());
        //lstPrinterList.Items.Add(new ListItem(printer));
        //lstPrinterList.Items.Add(printer);
        //System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox lstPrinterList = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox)Page.FindControl("ListBox1");
        //Zebra 110PAX4 (203 dpi)
        //lstPrinterList.Items.Insert(printer);
        //}
    }


    //private void lstPrinterList_OnClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    // Get the currently selected item in the ListBox.
    //    string curItem = lstPrinterList.SelectedItem.ToString();

    //    // Find the string in ListBox2.
    //    int index = lstPrinterList.DataTextField(curItem);
    //    //int index = lstPrinterList.FindString(curItem);
    //    //lstPrinterList.DataTextField(curItem);
    //    // If the item was not found in ListBox 2 display a message box, otherwise select it in ListBox2.
    //    if (index == -1)
    //        MessageBox.Show("Item is not available in ListBox2");
    //    else
    //        lstPrinterList.SetSelected(index, true);
    //}

    //private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    //{

    //    string str = File.ReadAllText("lpn.prn");
    //    str = str.Replace("BOX_TYPE", "boom");
    //    str = str.Replace("11111111", textBox1.Text);
    //    File.WriteAllText("lpn.prn", str);
    //            // Print the file to the printer.
    // RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter("\\\\Zebra-FDX ZM400 200 dpi (ZPL)", "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication4\\Prn Print\\bin\\Debug\\lpn.prn");  
    //}

    public void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        String prnFile = "lpn2.prn";
        string s = File.ReadAllText(prnFile);
        string printer;
        String Printer = lstPrinterList.SelectedItem.ToString();
        s = s.Replace("*description*", "snuffles");
        s = s.Replace("*barcode*", textBox1.Text);
        //File.WriteAllText("PPlpn.prn", s);
        //s = "^XA^LH30,30\n^FO20,10^ADN,90,50^AD^FDHello World^FS\n^XZ";
        printer = lstPrinterList.SelectedItem.Value;
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printer, s); 
        //RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(Printer, s);
        //Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.Replace(Request.Url.Query, "?__VIEWSTATE=%2%3D&ctl00%24MainContent%24textBox1=bp300&ctl00%24MainContent%24lstPrinterList=Shipping+Printer"));




    }
    protected void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}




public class RawPrinterHelper
{
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.
        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length;
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is what I created in C# and it worked out great. This is a web app.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to elaborate how this could be implemented?